# jquery automated scroll on prepend() success [How to]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm prepending the markup returned after an jquery ajax() call [the success part of the code as below]

```
success: function(html){
    $("ul#lists").prepend(html);
    $("ul#lists li:first").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

When the prepend is success, I want the page to automatically scroll to the position where the prepend is happening. I'm not sure of the syntax but the following is something like what I want.

```
success: function(html){
        if($("ul#lists").prepend(html)) {
            //Scroll to the position in the page where the prepend is about to happen
            //something similar to the href="#bookmark' in html. 
        }
        $("ul#lists li:first").fadeIn("slow");
    }
```

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin by Ariel Flesler.

Answer (score 1):

Hi u can use this , were id is element id where page has to be scrolled.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 2000);
```

Keep laughing.